# To INSERT a row into table from another table

Tags: sqlite, select, insert

I have the 'SchoolYearTeachingDays' table with just one column, in which are dates:

```
CREATE TABLE SchoolYearTeachingDays (
    aDate DATE PRIMARY KEY
                UNIQUE
);
```

I filled it with many dates which are unique. These dates excludes dates for Sundays and for Saturdays.
I have another, the 'TeachingSaturdaysInSchoolYear' table:

```
CREATE TABLE TeachingSaturdaysInSchoolYear (
    id            INT  PRIMARY KEY
                       UNIQUE,
    aDate      DATE,
    TimetableForTheDay TEXT
);
```

This table holds just two dates. These two dates are for two Saturdays. On these two Saturdays we have to teach students.
When I do the following query on this table, I get these two records:

2018-04-14

2018-05-05

I want to INSERT these two dates from the 'TeachingSaturdaysInSchoolYear' table into 'SchoolYearTeachingDays' table.

I am trying with this query:

```
INSERT INTO SchoolYearTeachingDays
 SELECT aDate FROM TeachingSaturdaysInSchoolYear
;
```

but I get this error:
Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: SchoolYearTeachingDays.aDate

How this query of mine works and why I get this error? How do I accomplish  my goal?

Best, Pal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are violating unique constraint by inserting duplicate values into the table SchoolYearTeachingDays.
2. To fix the error put a not in condition so that dates which are already inserted won't get inserted again into SchoolYearTeachingDays table.

Example,

```
INSERT INTO SchoolYearTeachingDays
 SELECT aDate FROM TeachingSaturdaysInSchoolYear T WHERE T.aDate NOT IN (SELECT S.aDate FROM SchoolYearTeachingDays S)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Raxit! I am still not understanding how the `SELECT` works in my query so it violating unique constraint? How many times want to  inserts the SELECT query the one of the date from the TeachingSaturdaysInSchoolYear table into SchoolYearTeachingDays table?

Comment: You are bulk inserting values using select statement which directly inserts whatever you get from TeachingSaturdaysInSchoolYear table. Since SchoolYearTeachingDays has unique dates the bulk insert fails on encountering duplicate values from your select query

Comment: _You are bulk inserting values using select statement which directly inserts whatever you get from TeachingSaturdaysInSchoolYear table._  To better understand this sentence, I must to ask again: when bulk inserting using select statement, in this example, how many times wants to insert one record from first table into second table?